# How can I create a mobile applications which react that can also serve as a website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I just finished my JavaScript course and I understand pretty well how things work.

I have started my React journey with a project in mind

So I want to create a mobile application using React Native and I also want that same application to be a website with domain and url since I want the website to work with with Google adsense.

I'm a little bit confused about things cause I want to use mysql database, node for back end and React for the front end, but I don't know if this is possible to just create one application that work as both mobile app and a website.

Thank for your assistance and advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A way to use practically the same code for a web frontend and mobile app is using tools like [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs). It make it quite simple, and also allow you to use some mobile native API's.
Here's how to integrate it with react js [Using Capacitor with React](https://capacitorjs.com/solution/react)